# how to databind to DevExpress TreeList

Tags: .net, devexpress, treelist

i want to databind hierarchical data from plain data to the ASPxTreeList, i checked the documentation online for the the databinding, this is the code i found:

```
 Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
 Imports System

 Partial Public Class Data_Hierarchical
     Inherits BasePage
     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
         If (Not IsPostBack) Then
             DataBind()
             treeList.ExpandToLevel(1)
         End If
     End Sub
 End Class
```

but how DataBind() is implemented?

Comment: how can i start a bounty on  this question

Comment: Could you please describe the format of your "plain data" and how you want it to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataBind is a method of the System.Web.UI.Control class and it is described in MSDN:

[Control.DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d.aspx)

In fact, we override this method in our code the way similar to the one described in the MSDN.

Comment: but this code sample doesn't show how do i pass the data to the treelist. is it a datatable?, a list, xml ?

Comment: You should either set a DataSource property programmatically or DatasourceID in design time.  If you set the DataSource property, you should do this on every Page_Init before the DataBind method call.  The TreeList can work with DataTables, IList and IHieararchical data source.  I would suggest that you check our demos, they should help you to understand how to bind TreeList to data.  Also, the following topic should be helpful:  http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3957